# How to find a word which contains digits in a string

Tags: c++, string, vector

I need to check words inside the string to see whether any of them contains digits, and if it isn't — erase this word. Then print out the modified string

Here's my strugle to resolve the problem, but it doesn't work as I need it to

```
void sentence_without_latin_character( std::string &s ) {
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::istringstream is (s);
    std::string word;
    std::vector<std::string> words_with_other_characters;

    while (is >> word) {
        std::string::size_type temp_size = word.find(std::ctype_base::digit);
        if  (temp_size == std::string::npos) {
            word.erase(word.begin(), word.begin() + temp_size);
        }
        words_with_other_characters.push_back(word);
    }

    for (const auto i: words_with_other_characters) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Can you use std::regex?

Answer (score 2):

This part is not doing what you think it does:

```
word.find(std::ctype_base::digit);
```

[`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) only searches for complete substrings (or single characters).

If you want to search for a set of some characters in a string, use [`std::string::find_first_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) instead.

Another option is testing each character using something like [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit), possibly with an algorithm like [`std::any_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) or with a simple loop.

Answer (score 0):

As Acorn explained, `word.find(std::ctype_base::digit)` does not search for the first digit. `std::ctype_base::digit` is a constant that indicates a digit to specific `std::ctype` methods. In fact there's a `std::ctype` method called `scan_is` that you can use for this purpose.

```
void sentence_without_latin_character( std::string &s ) {
  std::istringstream is (s);
  std::string word;

  s.clear();
  auto& ctype = std::use_facet<std::ctype<char>>(std::locale("en_US.utf8"));
  while (is >> word) {
    auto p = ctype.scan_is(std::ctype_base::digit, word.data(), &word.back()+1);
    if (p == &word.back()+1) {
      s += word;
      if (is.peek() == ' ') s += ' ';
    }
  }

  std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```